# The Coercivity of uniformly positive definite Matrix of Sobolev function

Tags: matrices, sobolev-spaces

For $u=(u^1,\ldots, u^N)\in W^{1,2}(\Omega,R^N)$ where $\Omega$ is bounded. We define
$$  E[u]=\int_\Omega g_{ij}(u)\nabla u^i\nabla u^jdx$$
where $G=(g_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N}$ is an given uniformly positive definite matrix, i.e. $\xi^T\cdot G(u)\cdot \xi\geq \alpha\|\xi\|^2>0$ no matter the value of $u$. Now my text book conclude that 
$$ E[u]\geq \lambda\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 $$
without prove. May it is a simple fact but I can not work it out. Could somebody help me to write done the details? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forgot $\|\xi\|^2$ in the definition the uniformly positive definite matrix. With this adjustment what you want to prove is straightforward.

Comment: No I didn't... This is why I confused...

Comment: @wisher So is your definition correct? Take $\xi=0$ see what happens.

Comment: I see what your point. Sorry it is an typo. But what I want to ask is that, as $u^j$ $u^i$ are different functions, we can not just apply the definition of positive definite matrix.